# PySpark: Getting a directory from path string

Tags: pyspark

I have a string which is my current working directory which is something like "Aw/Bt/Ce/Dr".
I should search for the string & retrieve "Bt".

Is there a way I could do that in PySpark.

TIA, Jagan

Answer (score 1):

If you are always interested in the directory name between the first and the second `/` then you can split the string on `/` and chose the second element.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.sql("select 'Aw/Bt/Ce/Dr' as path")
df.withColumn("output", F.split(F.col("path"), "/")[1]).show()
```

### Output

```
+-----------+------+
|       path|output|
+-----------+------+
|Aw/Bt/Ce/Dr|    Bt|
+-----------+------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_extract,col

df.withColumn("New",regexp_extract(col("Column_name"),'(Bt)',1))
```

Result:

```
+---+----------+---+  
| Id|      Name|New|     
+---+----------+---+  
|  1|     e    |   
|  2|Aw/Bt/C/Dr| Bt|  
|  3| A/B/Ce/Dr|   |  
+---+----------+---+
```